# .NET DB - Scaffolding - Keyless type error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

My first time working on a project solo, and first time attempting to scaffold models from an existing DB.
Please see attached pictures for the error.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SAPAS_LOCAL_TEST;Database=SAPAS_TEST;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Build started...
Build succeeded.

```
The key {'YearId'} cannot be added to keyless type 'TlkupYear'.
```

See the screenshot below:

[image]

I've noticed that in the DB this table has no keys, only values...
Any way to work around this issue?

Let me know how I can work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out, the table didn't have a PrimaryKey set.
Easy fix once I figured that out.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD PRIMARY KEY(COLUMN_NAME)
```

did the trick for me